# Logging in with wrong username and password as well

Tags: php, html, validation, authentication

It is logging in even with the incorrect user name and password, please help me figure out where the problem is. I want it to log in only and only if it matches the user name and password but it is entirely working wrong.

Here's the code:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="countries.php">
<p>  </p>
<table border=0 width=500px align=center>
  <tr>
<td>Enter User Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=text size=30 value="" name=t1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=password size=30 value="" name=t2>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type=reset value="Clear Form" name=b2>
</td>
<td><input type=submit value="Login Form" name=b4>
</td>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=submit value="Guest User" name=b5>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

 <hr />
 </center>

 <?php
 $t1="Maha";
 $t2="abc";
 if($t1 == "Maha" && $t2 == "abc")
 {

      header("countries.php");
      exit;
     echo " We are glad you are visiting us again. Lets plan yout tour together." ;

 }
 else {

     header("final.php");
     exit;
     echo " User name or password is incorrect. Try again.";
 }
 ?>

  </form>
```

Comment: **Sidenote:** You missed the `location` keyword on your `header` function.

Comment: You are defining your values -> `$t1="Maha"; $t2="abc";` so they will always be correct. Change to `$t1=$_POST['t1']; $t2=$_POST['t2'];`, in addition to the `location` missing from `header("Location: final.php")`

Answer (score 1):

You have some other problems, which will cause this to break in other ways, but it is always hitting the login state because you are comparing these variables (with hard coded values):

```
$t1="Maha";
$t2="abc";
```

to the hard coded credentials:

```
if($t1 == "Maha" && $t2 == "abc")
```

instead of reading user input through [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are posting the form on `countries.php`

your login code should be in `countries.php`

Also, you are missing the Location keyword within the header code:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

here is your modified php code that should be in **countries.php**:

```
<?php
 $t1=$_POST['t1'];
 $t2=$_POST['t2'];
 if($t1 == "Maha" && $t2 == "abc")
 {

      header("Location: countries.php"); // probably some other page since countries.php has the login verification logic.
      exit;
     echo " We are glad you are visiting us again. Lets plan yout tour together." ;

 }
 else {

     header("Location: final.php");
     exit;
     echo " User name or password is incorrect. Try again.";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion but it is still not working as in it still logs in on incorrect user-name and password.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is coming by POST.

```
if($_POST['t1'] == "Maha" && $_POST['t2'] == "abc")
```